# Using Dev org for commercial

Tags: developer-edition

If I am ok with limits for dev org and I want to use it as commertial app in my business, Is it legal?
Does Salesforce track using dev orgs like to determine if they are used as production? And will my data be as safe as in production org?
I am starting small business and buying production org is too expencive for me.

Comment: There is no any threat related to your data. Also there is no any salesforce's constraint if you are using for the commercial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A Developer Edition environment is a free, fully-featured copy of the Enterprise Edition environment, with less storage and users. DE is a logically separate environment, ideal as your initial development environment. You can sign-up for as many DE organizations as you need. This allows you to build an application designed for any of the Salesforce production environments.

1. Developer Edition is a special development license that **does not allow the conversion to production**.
2. Developer edition has a limited storage and we can not extend the storage capacity of Developer edition.

Hence, it is not advisable to use Devloper Edition as a Production Org for a Business.